# How to fill polygons with color

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a lot of convex and concave predefined polygons.
The example is:

[image]

As the SFML documentation says:

> ...SFML is unable to draw concave shapes. If you need to draw a concave shape, you'll have to split it into multiple convex polygons...

So, the 'concave' is crucial here.
Splitting algorithm can be hard to write (and also time-expensive to use), thousands of shapes - one in another. Any idea (or good practices) how to approach solving the problem?

Comment: Image looks like a demonically possessed Road Runner.

Comment: just totally random MS paint-made ;)

Comment: Addition to my "this is a duplicate"-comment: You can relatively easy try to triangulate the shape and then either draw the triangles individually or join them together into convex shapes. I know, the linked question is not for C++ or SFML, but the solutions aren't for actionscript either but more general.